# How to properly read in wave file sample rate in C++?

Tags: c++, hex

Just out of curiosity while learning both wave file format and C++, I stumbled on this [page](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) that details the canonical layout of wave format

Now, I tried to write a C++ program to read out the sample rate

```
char buffer[4];
// already read other values before reading sample rate
inFile.read(buffer, 4);
// conversion using little endian
sampleRate = (long) buffer[0] + ((long) buffer[1] << 8) + ((long) buffer[2] << 16) + ((long) buffer[3] << 24);
```

In the hex editor, I can see my sample wave file has sample rate as `44 ac 00 00`, which translates into 44100 rate. However, with the above code, I always end up with -21436

After some debugging, it turns out that the raw hex value "ac" should be translated into 172 in dec, but C++ assumed the hex value as "ffffffac", which translates to -84 in dec. If C++ just assumes it is plain "ac", I would have ended up with the correct sample rate value.

So the questions is, how do I read out the data from wave file and actually get the correct sample rate? Do I have to do some magic to strip away the leading "f"s ?

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: what's the type of `buffer`? try it with `unsigned`.

Comment: Any reason you're using `+` and not `|`?

Comment: @Xymostech, for bit patterns that don't overlap they're equivalent.

Comment: updated the original question with the buffer type. indeed, I used the default signed char[]. Also, inFile is a ifstream object. sampleRate is type of long

Comment: @Karoly, I started a similar thread with Andrew's answer down below. It seems that ifstream object's read() method doesn't take unsigned char*

I tried g++ compiler on Mac Mountain Lion, as well as cygwin's g++-3.exe compiler. Both complained about unsigned char*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to fix your code. The first is to ensure that unsigned arithmetic is used throughout by making everything unsigned. The second is to use a bit mask to remove the sign extensions.

```
sampleRate = ((long) buffer[0] & 0xff) + (((long) buffer[1] << 8) & 0xff00) + (((long) buffer[2] << 16) & 0xff0000) + ((long) buffer[3] << 24);
```

Comment: Aside from ifstream's read method not taking unsigned char buffer, the code you posted works great. It also does not appear to make assumptions about base system running big or small endians.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach is as follows:

```
// simply store bytes directly into sampleRate
long sampleRate = 0;
inFile.read(&sampleRate, 4);
```

This, as you may suspect, assumes your system is little Endian. To fix your example, you must avoid the sign extension that is taking place when you cast to long. Declare `buffer` of type `unsigned char`. See the following.

```
unsigned char buffer[4];
inFile.read(buffer, 4);
long sampleRate = (long)buffer[0] + ((long)buffer[1] << 8) + ((long)buffer[2] << 16) + ((long)buffer[3] << 24);
```

Comment: What is the type of your inFile object? is it also ifstream? I see a number of suggestions to use unsigned char[] (my original Q only used default signed char[]). However, if I use unsigned, g++ compiler goes haywire

`test.cpp:57: error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘char*’
test.cpp:57: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::read(_CharT*, std::streamsize) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’`


line 57 refers to `inFile.read(buffer, 4);`